# Add padding to the left of NumberPicker items

Tags: java, android

How do you add padding to the left of NumberPicker items, resulting in something similar to the picture below.

I was able to add whitespace using RelativeLayouts, but there are issues with that. (mainly that the added RelativeLayout doesn't detect scroll gestures)

I think I need to extend NumberPicker and do something, but I'm not sure what.

[image]

Here is my NumberPicker xml:

```
<NumberPicker
                    android:id="@+id/pars_left_numberPickerID"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                    android:elevation="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="190dp"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:theme="@style/numberPicker"
                    android:visibility="visible" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`android:paddingLeft="10dp"`
```

Just type padding and explore ther options.

Comment: Adding `android:PaddingLeft` tag to the NumberPicker seems to have no effect.

Comment: I think it's an namespace issue try clearing the namespace and re-importin the namspace.

Answer (score 0):

After giving up on the default NumberPicker, I was able to get this working by importing and modifying this 3rd party NumberPicker: https://github.com/Carbs0126/NumberPickerView

This allowed me to create a paddingLeft attribute that the number picker will respect.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the width being statically set with `android:layout_width="90dp"` (the reason why it even looks wonky) with `wrap_content` and you might not be facing this home-made problem. Besides, `Widget.Material.NumberPicker` can be styled to some degree.